# Generate Insert SQL Statement from a .csv file

Tags: java, sql, excel, csv

I need some help, ideas, support at the beginning.

I want to write an application in java, which reads a .csv file and creates a .sql file with the appropriate Insert statements.

For Example:

```
Title;Author;Price
Java Foundation;Java;15
Excel Tutorial;Excel;25


INSERT INTO TABLE(TITLE,AUTHOR,PRICE) VALUES ('Java Foundation','Java',15);
```

In this case I am a little bit unknowing and don't know how to start properly.

Thanks ahead for your help!

---

**Update**

The example works fine, except for one case. If I want to convert the following .csv I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
Title;Forename;Surname
Mr.;Andy;Benson
Mrs.;Susi;
```

Because of this: `String[] values = lines.get(i).split(delimiter);`

It only puts `'Mrs.'` & `'Susi'` in the String Array, but it should also put one empty String `" "` in the Array.

Is there maybe another function/method to avoid this problem?! Usually it is common, that not every line is filled out in a .csv file.

**Solved** `String[] values = lines.get(i).split(delimiter, -1);`and split won't ignore empty fields

Comment: so what is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the java non-blocking class `Files` to read all the lines of your file using the `readAllLines` method and then use a template `String` and format it with the correct values using the `String` `format` method.

You then write your statements to a `.sql` using the `write` method in `java.nio.Files`.

```
    final String template = "INSERT INTO TABLE(%s,%s,%s) VALUES ('%s','%s',%s);";
    final String delimiter = ";";

    List<String> statements = new ArrayList<>();

    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("your-file.csv"));
    String[] columnNames = lines.get(0).split(delimiter);

    for (int i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        String[] values = lines.get(i).split(delimiter);
        statements.add(String.format(template, columnNames[0], columnNames[1], columnNames[2], values[0], values[1], values[2]));
    }

    Files.write(Paths.get("your-output.sql"), statements);
```

That is a short and simple way to achieve what you are asking. You will need to swap the word `TABLE` for your table name of course :)

**UPDATE:**

If you wanted to make the statement variable on the values in the `.csv` then you could use a nested `for` loop and amend the template

```
    for (int i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++) {

        String[] values = lines.get(i).split(delimiter);

        StringBuilder cols = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder vals = new StringBuilder();

        for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.length; j++) {
            cols.append(columnNames[j]);
            vals.append("'").append(values[j]).append("'");

            if (j != columnNames.length - 1) {
                cols.append(",");
                vals.append(",");
            }
        }

        statements.add(String.format(template, cols.toString(), vals.toString()));
    }
```

You would then have the template `String` as follows:

`final String template = "INSERT INTO TABLE (%s) VALUES (%s);";`

Comment: Thank you! I worked on your example and now the application will get the name of the .csv file and put it in the sql statement, so that the table name is correct (I posted it above). In your example columns and values are fixed. Is there a possibility to set the number of them variable, because I want to read different .csv files ?!

Answer (score 1):

untested, but pretty much:

```
public static String readWholeFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    final File file = new File(filename);
    final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    final byte[] data = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    fis.read(data);
    fis.close();
    return new String(data, "UTF-8");
}

public static String getInsertQuery(String filename, String TableName) throws IOException {
    final String content = readWholeFile(filename);
    final String[] lines = content.split("\n");

    if (lines.length < 2) return ""; // or throw new Exception("not enough lines);

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("INSERT INTO "+TableName+"("+lines[0].replace(";", ",")+") VALUES ");
    for (int i=1; i<lines.length; i++) {
        final String[] parts = lines[i].split(";");

        sb.append("(");

        for (int k=0; k<parts.length; k++) {
            sb.append("'"+parts[k]+"'");
            if (k != parts.length-1)
                sb.append(", ");
        }

        sb.append(")");
        if (i != lines.length-1)
            sb.append(", ");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use POI Jar to parse the csv and rest is to create a file with proper insert statements,so you can read the csv and in a loop add the insert statements to a file.